# How to validate file upload field?

Tags: php

I can't seem to validate file upload fields, here's my code:

```
<?php

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        if ($_POST['uploadFile']) {
            echo "File uploaded";
        } else {
            echo "No file attempted to be uploaded";
        }
    }

?>

<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="uploadFile" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

What is the mistake I'm making?

### EDIT

Came up with my own solution, may not be the best but it works:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $fileUpload = $_FILES['uploadFile'] ['name'];
        if (strlen($fileUpload) > 0) {
            echo "File uploaded.";
        } else {
            echo "No File attempted to be uploaded.";
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the superglobal your are looking for is $_FILES.

```
var_dump($_FILES); //to see what's happening with the uploaded files
```

To make sure a POST request is made you can use the following lines:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
   //A post request!
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As far as validation, take a look at `is_uploaded_file()` and read up on [Handling File Uploads](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php).

Comment: is_uploaded_file is deprecated.

Comment: @Alix, where have you determined that?

Comment: is_uploaded_file (PHP 4 >= 4.0.3), and http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php (Since PHP 4.2.0, PHP returns an appropriate error code along with the file array).

Comment: It's not E_DEPRECATED really, but there's no point in using it since the error index in $_FILES does the same and is more descriptive.

Comment: Also read this comment http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-uploaded-file.php#77875.

Comment: I definitely agree that there are better ways to determine/validate file uploads and that is_uploaded_file is *outdated*, but it's not technically deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

In this script we add some restrictions to the file upload. The user may only upload .gif or .jpeg files and the file size must be under 20 kb:

```
<?php
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")  
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")  
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg"))  
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000))  
      {  
      if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)  
    {  
    echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";  
    }  
  else  
    {  
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br />";  
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br />";  
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br />";  
    echo "Stored in: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];  
    }  
  }  
else  
  {  
  echo "Invalid file";  
  }  
?>
```

Comment: Or you could go to http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp where Acard21 found this code and see it for yourself.

Comment: Thats right, sorry for not posting the link myself, I didn't mean to take credit for that basic script.

Answer (score 0):

In file uploads with PHP, i think $_FILES[$file]['error'] is your best friend! it breaks it down in 8 possible scenarios, 0 meaning file upload went ok, so something like hereinafter should do the trick

```
if($_FILES[$file]['error']==0)
// proceed
else
switch($_FILES[$file]['error'])
// debugging
```